# Xamarin I need create some controls dynamically

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

I have some controls inside my database, when the app call an ID from database I will receive some controls and his positions in my layout.

I need to put it in an `AbsoluteLayout`, these controls are Labels, BarGraphs and others like this, but I don't know how I can instantiate from my ViewModel each of these controls.

I have the absolute layout and I'm creating a list of `ContentViews`, but how can I bind this list, or instantiate this in my `AbsoluteLayout` ??

**UPDATE**

I have made a bindable object like this:

```
 class BindableContentView : AbsoluteLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Items), typeof(ObservableCollection<ContentView>), typeof(BindableContentView), null,
            propertyChanged: (b, o, n) =>
            {
                (n as ObservableCollection<ContentView>).CollectionChanged += (coll, arg) =>
                {
                    switch (arg.Action)
                    {
                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                            foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
                                (b as BindableContentView).Children.Add((ContentView)v);
                            break;
                        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                            foreach (var v in arg.NewItems)
                                (b as BindableContentView).Children.Remove((ContentView)v);
                            break;                            
                    }
                };
            });

    public ObservableCollection<ContentView> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<ContentView>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public BindableContentView()            
    { }
}
```

And in XAML i worked with this piece of code:

```
  <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="absLayout">
     <objectlocal:BindableContentView Items="{Binding DynamicObjects, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
```

But it don't worked.

Comment: When you're using MVVM you should no instantiate any View-related controls from a ViewModel. You should have Views that are shown depending on the ViewModel itself.

Comment: Right, but i need create new controls like labels and bargraphs in runtime, because i don't know how many elements i will have, or what type elements they will be. I will know it when my app load this from the database.

Comment: Then you're not using MVVM. A good thing with WPF and MVVM is that you shouldn't "need" to create elements based on what you get from database. With MVVM you should have predefined elements in certain Views and then depending on what type of data you have you should use `DataTemplate` to display it.